# regex to allow 1 to 4 alphabet at starting of string and then followed by any number of digits

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to validate a field which can take input as following ways:

1. should take 1 to 4 alpha charcters.(but should start with alpha)
2. from 5th position to so on should take numbers.(no where from 5th should accept  alphabets)
3. in between 1-4 characters of alpha it should not allow numbers.
   4.even if first 4 characters are entered it should accept.(that 4 characters should be alpha.ex:"asdf")
   ^[a-zA-Z][0-9]$

i have many things and searched many sites.i could not find it.please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean `^[a-zA-Z]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: Can you give some examples of valid and invalid strings?

Comment: yes @dustmouse. example like crow1111111111

Comment: @RushiAyyappa - Okay, check out the link in my answer.

Comment: yes,it is working fine as i wanted.many thanks.but can you explain this? and i want it in other way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,4}\d*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/yH6pR3/1

It will only allow 1-4 alpha characters, and then only digits thereafter.  Digits are optional. You can change that by making it `\d+` instead.

I am wondering what you mean by digits only from 5th position onward.  What if there are three or less alpha at the start of the string?

**UPDATE:**

```
^(?:[A-Za-z]{1,4}|[A-Za-z]{4}\d+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/qQ8nR2/1

First it attempts to match just 1-4 characters.  If that fails, then it attempts to match 4 characters followed by 1 or more digits.

Comment: ,i am developing something that will take inputs of 1-4 characters .it means i can accept if he enters only one char or 4 chars.

Comment: i am sorry man i cannot accept your answer because it is accepting strings likr "s6565" as i said you ,first 4 characters must and should be in characters and no of characters can be any from minimum 1 to max of 4 at starting

Comment: yes,now this works awsome.but can you explain me this? thanks so much man!Happy coding!

Comment: No problem, it is using a `|` to try an alternate pattern if the first one fails.  So the first pattern is effectively `^[A-Za-z]{1,4}$` so it has to be only 1 - 4 characters.  If that fails, it attempts the second pattern which is effectively `^[A-Za-z]{4}\d+$`, which is four characters followed by one or more digits.

Comment: but why did you use ?: in the beginning

Comment: It means it's a non-capturing group.  If you're just checking for validity, it isn't really necessary in this case.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group

Comment: oops man..it is a bit tough to get into my brain..can you shortly tell me about non cpturing group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93725/discussion-between-dustmouse-and-rushi-ayyappa).

Answer (score 1):

For an answer off the top of my head:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}[0-9]+$
```

will match a string with the following break down:

1. `^` = Start of string
2. `[a-zA-Z]` = `a` through `z` (case-insensitive)
3. `{1,4}` = 1 to 4 times
4. `[0-9]+` = `one` or `more` numbers
5. `$` = End of string

Because each situation is different, I would suggest using an online regex tester to test certain strings of characters.

Comment: dear meeseeks, thanks for your answer,your regex will accept something like "asdf455555555555555".but if i give only "asdf" it wont accept.so can't take your answer

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Your unedited post did not say that it should accept "asdf" so that's why I included `[0-9]+`. If you wanted `zero` or `more` numbers then it would be `[0-9]*` but your welcome anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\d*
```

- `[a-zA-Z]` is for alpha chars
- `\d' is short for numbers
- `{1,4}` specify 1 to 4 chars
- `*` specify any number of digits (including none)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it this way:

```
^\p{L}{1,4}\d+$
```

`\p{L}{1,4}` matches any letter 1 to 4 times

`\d+` matches any digit one or more times